# Getting null for the content type of png image

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, struts

I am getting `null` value when I am trying to get the content type of `png` image

Below is how I am trying to get the content type in my `servlet`:

```
String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(image.getName());
```

I am getting `contentType = null` and `image.getName()` returns name of `png` image.

I tried other way to get the content type of the same `png` image:

```
String contentType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType("imageName.png");
```

Above code gives me `contentType = application/octet-stream`.

My question is why I am getting different content type for the same image, and what should I do so that I will get the correct content which is `image/x-png` for `.png` type of images

Comment: I am not using jdk 7, so java.io.Files option is close for me.

Comment: Have you tried apache FileUtils for your purpose?

Comment: No. I am using struts form bean for this.

Comment: That is okay, Which datatype you are using for this purpose? I would recommend to use FormFile.

Comment: Yup I am using the same, FormFile.

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be too late, but stumbled upon this today. In my case, the problem was:

> The MIME type of a file is retrieved from the application server. Most application servers, including IBM® WebSphere® Application Server and Tomcat, come with some predefined MIME types. However, many common file formats are still missing from the default types and must be defined by a server administrator.

Found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21269129)

Answer (score 0):

My solution :

```
String contentType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType("imageName.PNG");
//contentType = null

String contentType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType("imageName.png");
//work for me
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It could be improved by adding the content type you got, and how Vishrant could ensure that the value returned by their image.getName() function is valid input for getContentType.